# Student Council Election

Tags: algorithm, data-structures

Student council elections are work in an odd manner. Each candidate is assigned a unique
identification number. The University is divided into five zones and each zone proposes a
list of candidates that it would like to nominate to the Council. Any candidate who is
proposed by three or more zones is elected. There is no lower limit or upper limit on the
size of the Council. Design an algorithm to take proposed list of candidate from all five
zones as input (in sorted order) and calculate how many candidates are elected to the
Council. Illustrate your algorithm for the following example:
Suppose the candidates proposed by the five zones are:

```
 Zone 1: [5,12,15,62,87]
 Zone 2: [7,14,48,62,87,92]
 Zone 3: [5,12,14,87]
 Zone 4: [12,17,49,52,92,98]
 Zone 5: [5,12,14,87,92]
```

I think the hint here is sorted order but i couldn't find any ways to approach this problem.If anyone come up with solution please post it. Thank you.

Comment: Are you asking us to actually *do* your class work for you? Or do you want guidance?

Comment: Please give guidance

Comment: Guidance: search for "merge sort" on wikipedia.

Comment: Do I have to 5 way merge

Comment: Yes, it looks like that is what's intended. But note that you aren't creating an output array. You just determine how many of the 5 arrays have the smallest value. Then discard that value from all of the arrays.

Comment: Same question asked https://stackoverflow.com/q/60832459/56778, and closed as homework.

Comment: If the arrays are sorted, you can do a [k-way merge](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/K-way_merge_algorithm) in O(n log k) complexity, where n is the total number of items in all arrays, and k is the number of arrays. The benefit of using the k-way merge is that the memory requirement is O(k) rather than O(n).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have a simple idea.

1. Initialize a HashMap(key, value) with the key representing the candidate id and value representing the number of proposed.
2. Loop for each element of each zone.
3. If the element is not yet appeared, append new (key, value) with value 1, else increase value by 1.
4. Finally, you can check in hashmap and elect key with equal or greater than 3.

So, you can follow my Pseudocode

```
Hashmap map = new HashMap<int, int>()
ForEach z in ZoneLine
   ForEach e in z
      If containKey(e)
         put map[e] <- 1
      Else map[e]+=1
ForEach m in Map
   If map[m] >= 3
      return m
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Works, but requires O(n) extra memory for the hash table.

Comment: yes, you 're right. I have a little improvement is as follows: In `ForEach e in z` check map[m] >= 3 at the same time and return m if true, so I don't need to use `ForEach m in Map`.I think I can get better results.

Comment: That still requires you to have a map that can contain all of the items. Worst case, if every number in every zone is unique, you will have that many map entries. Imagine if each zone had a billion elements. Because the lists are sorted, you can use a k-way merge and you only need to keep 5 things in memory. It's a little harder to set up, but there's no limit on the size of the lists you can work with.

Comment: oh, that's what I'm looking for...thanks @JimMischel